Firebase error occurring during build in Flutter app
The code to add firebase in a flutter app does not work, causing the app to not build. The following error pops up (did not occur when using the web build of the app):
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform firebase-auth-22.3.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\ger81\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\53f3a323264ccff155272de0c3b13f19\transformed\jetified-firebase-auth-22.3.1-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform play-services-measurement-api-21.6.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:21.6.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\ger81\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\07dba32cabd2c5f0b2f4e3781e9709a7\transformed\jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.6.1-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform recaptcha-18.4.0.aar (com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\ger81\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0908529605fc19e2a4c0517ed23e8088\transformed\jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

I have added my SHA-1 certificate to firebase so that should not be an issue anymore. I suspect the issue is with gradle versioning or firebase versioning, but I am not sure. I tried altering the minsdk and target sdk versions, but that did not change the results. The code did run from another computer, however something, likely on the configuration part, is not working on my installation of android studio .
android/app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.censeo"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
`
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.censeo"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}

android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

I have tried solutions from a similar article, primarily enabling MultiDex, which has not fixed the issue. My updated code:
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.censeo"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.

        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}


You forget to enable multidex
Modify android/app/build.gradle to add the following sections in the appropriate places:
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1' 
}

